# understanding inline-block divs and its "margin" css property

Tags: css, crop, centering

I'm trying to understand this [code](http://dabblet.com/gist/6323019) in order to both crop and center an image.

I think I've understood most of it, but I'm still not figuring out why I need this:

```
.img-crop img{
    /* removes(sorta) image from the flow */
    padding-left: 100%;
    margin: -100% -100%;
}
```

I think `margin: -100% -100%` is for centering the image both vertically and horizontally, but why is it placed on the left of the container (and therefore: why do I need that padding-left: 100%)?

Comment: just a note - margin: -100% -100% is the same as margin: -100%

Comment: In the original example, that value was `margin: -999em -100%` but I was making some test. [here is the original example](http://dabblet.com/gist/4711695)

Comment: yea I saw that too, you should just grab it straight from the code, in this case the -999em comparing to -100% are different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how it works. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dW4Sp/4/) you can find an example I tried to write for you from scratch. The `image` has been replaced by a `div`, but since they are both displayed as `inline-block`, the last one is convenient for changing heights and play with it.

Let me say it's quite useful if you don't want to use jquery to heavily manipulate all your DOM! Crop and centering just in a bunch of css rulesets.